# Python - Delete a file with a certain character in it

Tags: python

I have a lot of duplicate files in a folder and I would like to delete the duplicate. As of now i have `FileA.jpg` and `FileA(1).jpg`. I would like to make a short script that open a directory and finds any file name that has a `(` and then delete it.

How would I do this?

Comment: list the files in a folder. check if '(' is in the file name and delete it. Could you show what have you tried?

Comment: I'd use regex foer this personally, think it'd be a little easier to manage.

Comment: Honestly, a better strategy might be to find all the files named FileA.jpg, FileA (1).jpg, ... FileA (N).jpg and then delete all except FileA (N).jpg and finally rename FileA (N).jpg to FileA.jpg. Why? Because FileA (N).jpg is the last file downloaded/copied with the original name FileA.jpg and is arguably the most valuable because of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OS` package.

```
import os

for filePath in os.listdir("/path/to/dir"):
    if "(" in filePath:
        os.remove(filePath)
```

Comment: Will also attempt to delete folders that have parentheses in their names, and trigger an exception.

Comment: Yes in that case rv.kvetch's answer would be the best way to go.

Comment: Careful, because os.listdir will only give you the file/folder names, not their full path. So if you're listing a folder that is not in the current working directory (CWD), you will accidentally try to delete a file with that name in the CWD. You should append the name of the folder you're listing: `os.remove(os.path.join("/path/to/dir", filePath))`

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the ways how it can be done (deleting files only):

```
from os import listdir
import os
from os.path import isfile, join

PATH_CONST = r'\temp'
myFiles = [f for f in listdir(PATH_CONST) if isfile(join(PATH_CONST, f))]

print(myFiles)

for file in myFiles:
    if '(' in file:
        os.remove(PATH_CONST+r'\\'+file)
```

Comment: Use `os.path.join` rather than manually construct paths (with the wrong slash).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [a regex](https://regex101.com/r/uOjQry/2) for this personally:

```
.*\(\d+\)
```

Code example (with `re` module)

```py
import os
import re


is_dupe_file = re.compile(r'\(\d+\)').search

for filePath in os.listdir("/path/to/dir"):
    if is_dupe_file(filePath):
        print('matches:', filePath)
```

For test purposes, I recommend to use a list with a few dummy filenames:

```
files = r"""
FileA(1).jpg
hello/FileA(33).jpg
FileA.jpg
FileB().jpg
hi\there\File1(test).jpg
FileB(a).jpg
FileB(23)
FileB(1234567).jpg
""".strip().split('\n')

for filePath in files:
    if is_dupe_file(filePath):
        print('matches:', filePath)
```

Out:

```
matches: FileA(1).jpg
matches: hello/FileA(33).jpg
matches: FileB(23)
matches: FileB(1234567).jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the os package
So first import os, then get the cwd or current working directory. This means whichever folder the python script is in, it will perform all the code for this specific folder. For instance, you put this .py file in the folder with all the duplicate files.

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()

#print all files in cwd
for file in os.listdir(cwd):
    if "(1)" in file: 
        print("Duplicate file found: " + file)
        os.remove(file)
    else:
        continue
```

You can change the (1) to whatever you want to search for. If you have more than one duplicate of each image, meaning it goes above 1, then just search for files with "(" in the name for example. I also added a print so that it tells you in the console which file is being deleted.

Hope it helps.